# Using dplyr's enquo to access Spark table columns via sparklyr

Tags: r, dplyr, lapply, sparklyr, nse

I would like to be ebale to use dplyr's [`enquo`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/programming.html) within `lapply` call while jumping through Spark table columns.

```
lapply(tbl_vars(sprkTbl),
       function(col_nme) {
           print(col_nme)
           # Enquoe column name
           quo_col_nme <- enquo(col_nme)
           print(quo_col_nme)

           sprkTbl %>%
               select(!!quo_col_nme) %>% 
               # do stuff
               collect -> dta_res
       }) -> l_res
```

However, when I try to run this code I keep on getting error:

> Error in `(function (x, strict = TRUE)`  :    the argument has already
>   been evaluated

I've isolated the error to [`enquo`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/programming.html):

```
>> lapply(tbl_vars(sprkTbl),
...        function(col_nme) {
...            print(col_nme)
...            # Enquoe column name
...            quo_col_nme <- enquo(col_nme)
...            # print(quo_col_nme)
...            
...            # sprkTbl%>%
...            #     select(!!quo_col_nme) %>% 
...            #     # do stuff
...            #     collect -> dta_res
...        }) -> l_res
[1] "first_column_in_spark"
```

*(and then the same error)*

> Error in `(function (x, strict = TRUE)`  :    the argument has
>   already been evaluated

I want to understand why `enquo` can't be used like that. `tbl_vars` returns an ordinary character vector, shouldn't the `col_name` be a string? I would envisage for the syntax to work in the same manner as in:

```
mtcars %>% select(!!enquote("am")) %>% head(2)
              am
Mazda RX4      1
Mazda RX4 Wag  1
```

but, clearly this is not the case, when called from within lapply.

---

## Edit

leaving the sparklyr aspect on side, a better and more reproducible example can be provided:

```
lapply(names(mtcars),function(x) {
    col_enq <- enquo(x)
    mtcars %>% 
        select(!!col_enq) %>% 
        head(2)
})
```

produces identical error.

#### Desired results

The old **`_`**-based syntax works

```
lapply(names(mtcars),function(x) {
    # col_enq <- enquo(x)
    mtcars %>% 
        select_(x) %>% 
        head(2)
})
```

In a word, I want to achieve the same functionality by jumping to Spark table columns and I would prefer not use deprecated `select_`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do I understand your question correctly that you are interested in this result? Or are you bound to use `enquo` instead of `quo`?

```
library(dplyr)

lapply(names(mtcars),function(x) {
  col_enq <- quo(x)
  mtcars %>% 
    select(!!col_enq) %>% 
    head(2)
})
#> [[1]]
#>               mpg
#> Mazda RX4      21
#> Mazda RX4 Wag  21
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>               cyl
#> Mazda RX4       6
#> Mazda RX4 Wag   6
#> 
#> [[3]]
#>               disp
#> Mazda RX4      160
#> Mazda RX4 Wag  160
#> 
#> [[4]]
#>                hp
#> Mazda RX4     110
#> Mazda RX4 Wag 110
#> 
#> [[5]]
#>               drat
#> Mazda RX4      3.9
#> Mazda RX4 Wag  3.9
#> 
#> [[6]]
#>                  wt
#> Mazda RX4     2.620
#> Mazda RX4 Wag 2.875
#> 
#> [[7]]
#>                qsec
#> Mazda RX4     16.46
#> Mazda RX4 Wag 17.02
#> 
#> [[8]]
#>               vs
#> Mazda RX4      0
#> Mazda RX4 Wag  0
#> 
#> [[9]]
#>               am
#> Mazda RX4      1
#> Mazda RX4 Wag  1
#> 
#> [[10]]
#>               gear
#> Mazda RX4        4
#> Mazda RX4 Wag    4
#> 
#> [[11]]
#>               carb
#> Mazda RX4        4
#> Mazda RX4 Wag    4
```

Comment: Correct, with the caveat that ultimately I want to apply this to a spark table but this a side point now. So why `quo` not `enquo`?

Comment: Tbh, I am always confused which one to use, I end up trying both and using the one that works...

Comment: Typing `rlang::quo` at the console confuses me even further... `function (expr) 
{
    enquo(expr)
}` ... or https://github.com/tidyverse/rlang/blob/master/R/quo.R#L180

Comment: @Konrad I think you use `quo()` if the variable passed to the function is quoted and `enquo()` if not. In your example, one can imagine that what lapply is doing is calling the function as `function("mpg")` rather than (no quotes) `function(mpg)`. If it was doing the latter, then you'd have to use `enquo()`.

Comment: @Aurèle `quo()` creates an expression in place while `enquo()` creates an expression that comes from one level up. This is why `quo()` is a simple wrapper around `enquo()`.

@hugo If the variable is alread quoted you shouldn't quote it again. You should just unquote it. But that isn't the case here, `x` will be a string not a quoted expression. The `quo()` here is misleading and serves no useful purpose. It just delays the evaluation of `x` (a string). You should just unquote `x` without sticking it in a quosure, `select()` supports strings, e.g. `select(mtcars, "cyl")`.